# Updating variable using function result on window resize Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to update global variable on the fly (window resize).
body_size variable should contain result of the function below it.I do understand that variable sits out of scope,however I have no idea how to pass it out. Please help. Please See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var body_size; // this updates correctly

  var resizeTimer;

  function setContainerWidth() {
    body_size = $('.container').width();
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {

    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

      setContainerWidth();
     

    }, 200);

  });
  setContainerWidth();
  console.log(body_size);

  var SlidesInView = 3; // this should update depending on result below :
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    setContainerWidth(); // to check width on resize?
    if (body_size => 980) {
      SlidesInView = 4; // change SlidesInView above if condition is met.
    } else if (body_size <= 640) {
      SlidesInView = 1; //change SlidesInView above if condition is met.
    }
  });

  console.log(SlidesInView);
  }); // doc ready
```

```css
.container{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Basically top variable body_size should update itself with a value whenever user resizes window.

Comment: There is nothing unexpected here.. It actually updates your variable. But inside `window.resize` which triggers only when you resize the `window`. The `console.log` is in `document.ready` and by the time it gets logged, the `event` has not been triggered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `body_size` is getting assigned only on window resize event and its undefined initially when the `console.log` is executed.

I have modified it to assign on the load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var body_size; // this should hold the value of function below. This should get updates on window resize.

    var resizeTimer;
  
    function setContainerWidth() {
      body_size = $('.container').width(); 
    }
  
    $(window).resize(function() {

      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

        setContainerWidth(); 
        console.log(body_size); //retrieves actual width.

      }, 200);

    });
  
    setContainerWidth();
    console.log(body_size); //retrieves undefined, which means that body_size at the top is not updating.
  }); // doc ready
```

```css
.container{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you should not modify the script to assign on load, as the op wants to update it on the fly. His mistake, as you correctly detected is to assume that the outer console.log is executed after each resize, so the best we can do is to explain the difference between the op's expectation and reality as precisely as we can to help him/her understand the fundamentals.

Comment: It seems that i was chasing wind all morning. This does retrieve width on the fly. I have added it to my code. I have to compare body_width on window resize to determine hove many blocks to show. SlidesInView is not updating even though body_size is. I am trying to compare condition on window resize, but again it seems that I am missing something. Final idea is to get width for container then check which condition is met and retrieve variable value(SlidesInView)..Please check my snippet above

Comment: @user7121582, your original problem of body_size refresh was answered twice. If any of these answers are solving your initial problem, then you can accept it. The update reflects a new problem and should be eloquently asked in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us clarify the situation:

1. `body_size` is not top-level, since it is inside `$(document).ready(function() {/*...*/});` If you want to make it top-level, remove it from the `function` and declare it outside of it.
2. The `body_size` you declared is the very same variable you update inside your event, since there is no variable with the very same name shadowing it, so your assumption that it is not updated and it is different from the one you use inside your event is mistaken.
3. The `console.log` outputting the wrong value is executed before you `resize` the `window`, as your `script` is executing before that.

To make sure you understand the way the things work, try the following script:

```
  var body_size; // this should hold the value of function below. This should get updates on window resize.
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var resizeTimer;
    $(window).resize(function() {

      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

        body_size = $('.container').width(); 

      }, 200);

    });
  }); // doc ready
```

Open the page and the dev tools. Resize your `window` and then paste this into the console:

```
console.log(body_size); //retrieves actual width.
```

Voila! body_size was updated!